# Что делает объект component в методах run в задаче ниже?

Tags: java

Почему если, например в последнем классе (`DecoratorMyRunnableImpl`) закомментировать строку `component.run()` - то строка `"RunnableImpl body"` не будет выводиться?

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(new DecoratorRunnableImpl(new DecoratorMyRunnableImpl(new RunnableImpl()))).start();
    }

    public static class RunnableImpl implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("RunnableImpl body");
        }
    }

    public static class DecoratorRunnableImpl implements Runnable {
        private Runnable component;

        public DecoratorRunnableImpl(Runnable component) {
            this.component = component;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.print("DecoratorRunnableImpl body ");
            component.run();
        }
    }

    public static class DecoratorMyRunnableImpl implements Runnable {
        private Runnable component;

        public DecoratorMyRunnableImpl(Runnable component) {
            this.component = component;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.print("DecoratorMyRunnableImpl body ");
            component.run();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну вы же его закомментировали) Почему он должен вывестись?)

Comment: то есть это строка запускает метод run следующего объекта?

Comment: Не следующего, а одного единственного, который вы в конструктор передаете

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При выполнении `component.run();` происходит запуск метода поля `component` класса `RunnableImpl`:

```
  public void run() {
            System.out.println("RunnableImpl body");
        }
```

Соответственно если его коментить, то вывода текста не произойдет.

Comment: поставьте галочку если ответ помог